# Distribution of google play services version

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console

Our app is being distributed in places where internet connectivity is not always available and the google play services version is not always being updated. Except for monitoring it by myself, does the google play console gives any ability to view this metric, I couldn't find it in the official documentation:

> When you select a dimension, you'll see a table under the chart that
>   shows your app's data breakdown for a specific day. To change the date
>   shown, click in the chart or use the "Displayed on table" drop-down.
>
> Android Version: Android OS version reported from the user's device
>   Device: Users' device Marketing Name and Device Name (e.g. Google
>   Nexus 7/Flo) Country: Users' country Language: Users' Android OS
>   language setting Carrier: Users' wireless carrier (when applicable)
>   App Version: Version of your app To view your app versions by
>   distribution channels (including alpha, beta, and staged rollouts),
>   select the channel from the top of the table. A label will be added to
>   any alpha or beta versions currently being distributed, as well as
>   versions that weren't promoted to production. Once a version is
>   promoted to production, this label is removed. You can still see this
>   version in the list.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082832/1870447 - basically as of 2014, it seemed 90% of users have up to date version installed